# Stroke-width not associated with actual set-value (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape, export, stroke, line-art

When setting the stroke-width of a line, the stroke width appears to change in Inkscape (okay.. good). However I believe the amount that it changes is not actually equal to the value set. For example, when changing the stroke-width, I can see the outline of the stroke changing (blue lines) and they are grossly outside of the actual stroke coloured in black. Both change when changing the stroke-width, but the stroke itself seems to not be filled in to the value set (defined by the blue lines I'm assuming). Image below to explain this.

[image]

There are 2 other diagnostic problems which I think are also related to the problem:

A) when zooming in, the stroke-width seems to decrease (physically I think this should increase since the stroke width is set constant by me (1mm for example). Image below to explain this.

[image]

B) when saving the image as a either a .pdf or an .eps, or even exporting it as a .pdf, the stroke-widths are not as they appear in the .svg file when displayed in Inkscape. Image below to explain this. This is the main problem, that the stroke-width displayed in Inkscape is not constant when zooming and that therefore the stroke-width which appears in Inkscape (at a particular zoom) is not what is displayed after saving the image (to a .pdf for example).

[image]

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the way in which I'm defining the stroke? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong to not 'permanently' set the stroke-width to it's real/user-defined units?

I am in 'Normal' mode, not 'Outline' mode.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I created strokes in Inkscape at the sizes you described, along with some hairline guides for measurement, then Saved As PDF, and when I zoom to view them using Adobe Reader, the strokes are the correct size.  Here's [a screenshot](https://imgur.com/j1UjoBF).

Comment: Interesting..I actually just solved the issue (I think). I had to go and manually adjust the .xlm of each object to be "vector-effect:"non-scaling-stroke". I now have two questions: A) is there a way to get this option to be default? and B) my dimensions now seem not to be real. For example, I have two lines which are set to the same stroke length, but have obviously different thicknesses. I would like real-world dimensions of the stroke width..

Comment: When zooming out again, the hairlines and small lines get messed up, but that's likely because Adobe Reader is trying its hardest to make the hairlines visible, which would otherwise be too thin to display on a computer screen.  I don't think there is an actual problem here. It's just the way the PDF viewer is rendering the lines so that they are still visible on screen.